# Can't connect to db via php

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if there is something wrong with my code or database.

I created this php code for connect to my db.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php
      function OpenCon() {
        $dbhost = "xxxx.freesqldatabase.com";
        $dbuser = "someuser";
        $dbpass = "somepass";
        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
        return $conn;
      }

      /* close connection */
      $mysqli->close();
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since is only test enviroment I'm attaching to my code even credentials. For some reason I still getting connection error:

```
GET 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

To be honest I have no clue what is wrong. I copy pasted this code since this should work as connection to database. Since connection obviously do not works I don't know if else didn't returned that Connect failed message.

Comment: Is `OpenCon` being called? Perhaps try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` to view any script errors. Using `or die(mysqli_error())` may give you more details about the mysql connection.

Comment: `$mysqli` is not defined. I also wouldn't define a function like that in an HTML page.

Comment: You just posted your database credentials on the public internet. **CHANGE YOUR CREDENTIALS RIGHT NOW** and always redact them before posting. Editing won't change the fact that these are now compromised.

Comment: Add this line: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`  before `new mysqli()` and remove `or die()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi from what I understand your making a connection from your Database. You only copy pasted this code and test it in a local server. First thing's first your should separate your html file to your php file. Doing this will make debugging more friendlier.

What kind of local test server are you using is XAMPP, WAMPP, LAMPP? If you're using one these things try this, change your DBHOST to localhost and test it.

Comment: Note, when you get to >50 rep, you can post comments for asking for clarification. In general, things like "*What kind of local test server are you using*" are not appropriate for answers. Use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain this in detail to you

Iam using 000webhost to host my website as it is free.

Use the following php file to connect to database

Name this file as db.php

'  <?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbusername","password","databasename");

?> '

Try to include this php file in required php file by using below command
Suppose if you have a file named info.php then simply copy paste below code after creating above mentioned db.php

'<?php

include 'db.php';

?>'

So half of the problem is solved.

if you are using phpmyadmin then default username will be "root" and default password will be ""

The mentioned process is working fine for me.

My basic website i created recently: [examstuff](http://examstuff.000webhostapp.com)